# CSS align and size

Tags: css, height, vertical-alignment

I am designing a layout and I am having two difficulties:

1) Don' t understand why the height of the div where calendar is in (green), is different from its parent.

2) I put a ul inside a div and want to set background color '#d1d2e0' to it (full width). It's going only to the 'Link four'.

[image]

```css
div.container
{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
background: #005884;
}

div.left
{
float:left;
width:160px;
margin:0;
padding:1em;
color: #d1d2e0;
background: green;
}

h3.header
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

div.right
{
margin-left:190px;
padding:1em;
text-align: right;
}

label.year{
 padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    margin: 0;
 background: #d1d2e0;
 color: #36384e;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d2e0;
}

select#DropYear{
 background: #36384e;
 color: #d1d2e0;
 width: 70px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 text-align-last: center;
}

div.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
 color: 5px soldi red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #005884;
    background-color: #d1d2e0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

a.last { border-right: none; }

li.nav {
 display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

.form{
 width: auto;
    height: 60px;
 background: lightgrey;
}

select.form{
}

.content{
 margin: 5px 0px;
 width: auto;
    height: 150px;
 background: yellow;
}

.footer{
 width: auto;
    height: 20px;
 background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><h3 class="header">Calendar</h3></div>
  <div class="right">
    <label class="year" for="DropYear">Year</label><!--
    --><select id="DropYear" class="drop">
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#" class="last">Link four</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="form"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1

You should be using `border-box` to make sizing easier:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then give your `.container` a height and tell it's children to inherit it.

## 2

Next, get rid of `display: table-cell;` on `div.nav` and actually give it a background color. I don't see where you were trying to set it, at all.

```
background: #d1d2e0;
```

Also, this property makes no sense:

```
color: 5px solid red;
```

It should be either `border: 5px solid red;` or `color: red;`.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.container
{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
background: #005884;
height: 62px;
}

div.left
{
float:left;
width:160px;
margin:0;
/*padding:1em; don't need this */
color: #d1d2e0;
background: green;
height: 100%;
}

h3.header
{
padding: 0 0 0 1em;
margin:0;
line-height: 62px;
height: 62px;
}

div.right
{
margin-left:190px;
padding:1em;
text-align: right;
}

label.year{
 padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    margin: 0;
 background: #d1d2e0;
 color: #36384e;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d2e0;
}

select#DropYear{
 background: #36384e;
 color: #d1d2e0;
 width: 70px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 text-align-last: center;
}

div.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
 /*color: 5px solid red; was this supposed to be "border" ? */
    /*display: table-cell; don't need this */
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #d1d2e0; /* you weren't setting this */
}

ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #005884;
    background-color: #d1d2e0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

a.last { border-right: none; }

li.nav {
 display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

.form{
 width: auto;
    height: 60px;
 background: lightgrey;
}

select.form{
}

.content{
 margin: 5px 0px;
 width: auto;
    height: 150px;
 background: yellow;
}

.footer{
 width: auto;
    height: 20px;
 background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><h3 class="header">Calendar</h3></div>
  <div class="right">
    <label class="year" for="DropYear">Year</label><!--
    --><select id="DropYear" class="drop">
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#" class="last">Link four</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="form"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Serg it's nice. Just help me out to center 'Calendar' inside div with class 'nav'.

Comment: @ElioFernandes there's no "Calendar" inside the `div.nav`. Please explain what you're trying to do a little better.

Comment: I am sorry! I meant div 'left'

Comment: @ElioFernandes updated my example with `text-align: center;`

Comment: Forgot to mention that was vertically and not horizontally.

Comment: @ElioFernandes updated, use `height` and `line-height` of the same size, matching the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `div.right` `padding:1rem` to `padding: 12px` and your issue will be fixed. Having a `1rem` padding expands it thus it is bigger than the left part.  Or you can use `padding: 1rem 1rem 12px 1rem;` so you get 1rem on all sides but 12px only on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You could move the right container into the left container and then just change some paddings (e.g. add padding to h3 and drop from .left). The smaller container, .left in this case, will then grow to all its content to fit.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><h3 class="header">Calendar</h3>
  <div class="right">
    <label class="year" for="DropYear">Year</label><!--
    --><select id="DropYear" class="drop">
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>  
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for your links, float them all left and set their width to 25%. You will also need to lose the display:table-cell from the containing div